# Could the commented "global code" also be excuted?

Tags: python

I don't know why the output is different when commenting out the seventh line. The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import time    
def loop(thread_name):      
    if False:
        print "1111"   #The print is only used to prove this code block indeed not excute 
        global dict_test   # The output will be different when commenting this line code
    else:
        dict_test = {}
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        i+=1
        print  "thread %s %s" % (thread_name,id(dict_test))
        time.sleep(1)

t1=threading.Thread(target=loop,args=('1'))
t2=threading.Thread(target=loop,args=('2'))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

If the explanation is that the global variable is precompiled no matter which condition is matched, why will the following code report an error ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import time    
def loop(thread_name):        
    if False:
        print "1111"   #The print is only used to prove this code block indeed not excute 
        global dict_test   # The output will be different when commenting or uncommenting this line code 
    else:
#        dict_test = {}
        pass
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        i+=1
        print  "thread %s %s" % (thread_name,id(dict_test))
        time.sleep(1)

t1=threading.Thread(target=loop,args=('1'))
t2=threading.Thread(target=loop,args=('2'))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Nice quirk; even I was a bit fooled by it.

Comment: Hi Alex, my question is that I don't know why the output of my program is different when comment dict_test = {} or remvoe the comment.  You could take a try on your PC first.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the name of a variable Python searches:

- the local scope
- the scope of any enclosing functions
- the global scope
- the built-ins

([source](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces))

`if` and other flow control structures are not mentioned here. Thus, the scope inside the `if` is the same as outside, thus an existing variable `dict_test` is made global, no matter if this block is being executed or not.

This might be surprising, but that's how it is defined.

The output for me is

```
thread 1 50663904
thread 2 50667360
thread 1 50667360
thread 2 50667360
thread 1 50667360
thread 2 50667360
...
```

So initially, when both Threads start off at the same time the two variables are independent. Starting with the second iteration, they both reference the same global variable.

Comment: Hi, Thorsten. Thanks for your responser, But I'm still a bit puzzled. If that is so, why my second program will report error (global name 'dict_test' is not defined)?

Comment: I corrected my explanation, maybe this time I'm not missing the point.

Comment: I have a further understanding about global block. Thanks very much.   But.... Is my second program normal on your pc ?... why I always get error?...

Comment: The second program isn't running on my PC as well, as you never define dict_test. It has to be defined to be made global.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether the if statement is executed, the global statement applies. So when commenting out the global statement, the assignment of dict_test applies to the local scope.